# Unpack *args to string using ONLY format function

Tags: python

As in the title, how to unpack `*args` to string using **ONLY** `format`  function (without `join` function), so having:

```
args = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

trying something like that (pseudocode):

```
'-{}-'.format(*args)
```

I will get:

```
'-a-b-c-'
```

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction of not using the standard function that does exactly the job you want done?

Comment: @spectras for educational purposes?

Comment: Is there anything special about it being `*args` though, not just any list with `str`-able elements?

Comment: ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) I'm not sure 'how to work around a perfectly suitable solution' qualifies as an actual problem.

Comment: @chepner who told that it's not true?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** There you go:

```
("-{}" * len(args) + "-").format(*args)
```

*Before I realized that it shouldn't use `join()` it was:*

```
"-{}-".format("-".join(["{}"] * len(args)).format(*args))
```

Comment: OP asked without `join` function.

Answer (score 2):

With a slight modification of the *format string* into `'{}-'`:

```
>>> args = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l = len(args)
>>> ('{}-'*(l+1)).format('', *args)
'-a-b-c-'
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `.join`:

```
from functools import reduce
l = [1,2,3]
s = reduce('{}{}-'.format, l, '-')
print(s)
```